# Continuously get the difference of integers in an array until the array size becomes one

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist, integer

I have an array:

```java
int[] array= {5, 7, 16, 3, 2}
```

I want to develop an application that takes the difference of the elements up to a single element in the array.

- Array → {5, 7, 16, 3, 2}
- [1] Loop → {2, 9, -13,  -1}
- [2] Loop → {7, -22, 12}
- [3] Loop → {-29, 34}
- [4] Loop → {63}

The result of the algorithm to be developed should be **63** in this case. How can I develop this algorithm?

Comment: Hi Siri! Can you edit into your post your attempt at a solution please?

Comment: Hint: There is some connection to [Pascal's Triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle).

Comment: I feel like this would be a good code golf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    int[] temp = {5, 7, 16, 3, 2};
    int[] temp2 = new int[temp.length];
    while (temp.length > 1) {
        temp2 = new int[temp2.length - 1];
        for (int i=0; i < temp.length - 1; i++) {
            temp2[i] = temp[i + 1] - temp[i];
        }
        temp = temp2;
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(temp));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about an application, but I can help with the function. Your goal can be accomplished with only a few lines of code if you use recursion. If the array that is passed is of length one, the value is returned. This will happen after as many recursive steps as are needed. It would be good to include an exception if the passed array is of length 0, but that is not strictly necessary.

```
public int takeDifferences(int[] arr) {
    if (arr.length > 1) {
        int[] newArr = new int[arr.length - 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
            newArr[i] = arr[i + 1] - arr[i];
        }
        return takeDifferences(newArr);
    }
    return arr[0];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a pity you did not dive into this trying to derive rules, applying some cleverness. *(That is what gives the most fun.)*

It is indeed a variant of *Pascal's triangle* as commented.
You can do it **symbolically**, without regarding to the array values, and derive a formula for an array of *(n+1)* elements.

| n (max index) | formula |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | a0 |
| 1 | -a0 + a1 |
| 2 | a0 - 2.a1 + a2 |
| 3 | -a0 + 3-a1 -3.a2 + a3 |
| 4 | a0 - 4.a1 + 6.a2 - 4.a3 + a4 |

The binomial formula fits with a coefficient of *a[i]* being: *-(-1)<sup>i</sup>.(n over i)*. The proof I will leave to you.

```
5 - 4*7 + 6*16 - 4*3 + 2 = 7 - 40 + 96 = 63
```